# How to get record from table Named Employee with the Foreign Key named ManagerId reference itself empId

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am stuck in this problem in which I am trying to getting a record from Employee table which has five columns named EmpId, Name, Age, Post and ManagerId. 
ManagerId is a foreign key and referencing table to Employee table of EmpId . It Means Manager is also an employee of company.

The Problem is I want to get a record that will contain empId, Name And Manager Name which is associated with an employee record. So what will be the mysql query for this. This is Table information :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `employee`;
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `empId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Name` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `Age` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `Post` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `managerId` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`empId`),
  KEY `FK_employee_1` (`managerId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_employee_1` FOREIGN KEY (`managerId`) REFERENCES `employee` (`empId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Left Join with Self.

```
SELECT e1.empId, e1.Name,  
       e2.Name AS manager_name 
FROM   employee e1 
       LEFT JOIN employee e2 
       ON e1.managerId = e2.empId
```